# "Hello world" with ASNA Visual RPG

Tags: rpg, asna-visual-rpg

I am new to ASNA Visual RPG. I spent hours in searching how to print a string in ASNA Visual RPG 9.x. But no luck on finding how to print a simple "hello world" String.

Can someone show me how to print "hello world" in the console?

Example in VB (hope that you could translate it to ASNA Visual RPG)

```
Sub Main ()
    Dim text As String
    text = "Hello World"
    Console.WriteLine(text)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: oh NO! RPG isn't dead YET?! :^)

Comment: it's in old RPG here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HelloWorldInManyProgrammingLanguages

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for all the trouble guys.. I just found out the answer. I am using Visual Studio 2008 for ASNA Visual RPG. To print "Hello World", all we need to do is to type:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
```